# MVC Model attribute to HTML attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

Is there are anyway to embed attribute to html input tag that has set in the model?

Code

```
[Required]
[StringLength(20)]
public string Username { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(20)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Expected Render Ouput:

```
<input id="Username" name="Username" maxlength="20" type="text" required="required" />
<input id="Password" name="Password" maxlength="20" type="password" required="required" />
```

I don't want JavaScript validation I want HTML validation

Comment: I think the only way would be to make an HTML helper that generates the HTML markup and looks for those attributes while doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way but you will have to do the customization yourself

You can take a look at the source code of how they implemented it using `HtmlHelper` extensions

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs

You're going to need to look at the following to get what you want for the two inputs referenced above

For the Text input

```
MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(...);
```

For the Password imput

```
MvcHtmlString PasswordFor<TModel, TProperty>(...);
```

They primarily use the following helper to construct the markup

```
// Helper methods

private static MvcHtmlString InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, string name, object value, bool useViewData, bool isChecked, bool setId, bool isExplicitValue, string format, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "name");
    }

    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", HtmlHelper.GetInputTypeString(inputType));
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true);

    string valueParameter = htmlHelper.FormatValue(value, format);
    bool usedModelState = false;

    switch (inputType)
    {
        case InputType.CheckBox:
            bool? modelStateWasChecked = htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(bool)) as bool?;
            if (modelStateWasChecked.HasValue)
            {
                isChecked = modelStateWasChecked.Value;
                usedModelState = true;
            }
            goto case InputType.Radio;
        case InputType.Radio:
            if (!usedModelState)
            {
                string modelStateValue = htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string)) as string;
                if (modelStateValue != null)
                {
                    isChecked = String.Equals(modelStateValue, valueParameter, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                    usedModelState = true;
                }
            }
            if (!usedModelState && useViewData)
            {
                isChecked = htmlHelper.EvalBoolean(fullName);
            }
            if (isChecked)
            {
                tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", valueParameter, isExplicitValue);
            break;
        case InputType.Password:
            if (value != null)
            {
                tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", valueParameter, isExplicitValue);
            }
            break;
        default:
            string attemptedValue = (string)htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", attemptedValue ?? ((useViewData) ? htmlHelper.EvalString(fullName, format) : valueParameter), isExplicitValue);
            break;
    }

    if (setId)
    {
        tagBuilder.GenerateId(fullName);
    }

    // If there are any errors for a named field, we add the css attribute.
    ModelState modelState;
    if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out modelState))
    {
        if (modelState.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            tagBuilder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);
        }
    }

    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));

    if (inputType == InputType.CheckBox)
    {
        // Render an additional <input type="hidden".../> for checkboxes. This
        // addresses scenarios where unchecked checkboxes are not sent in the request.
        // Sending a hidden input makes it possible to know that the checkbox was present
        // on the page when the request was submitted.
        StringBuilder inputItemBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        inputItemBuilder.Append(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));

        TagBuilder hiddenInput = new TagBuilder("input");
        hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("type", HtmlHelper.GetInputTypeString(InputType.Hidden));
        hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("name", fullName);
        hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("value", "false");
        inputItemBuilder.Append(hiddenInput.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputItemBuilder.ToString());
    }

    return tagBuilder.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
}
```